# What is the purpose of the resistors in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, circuit-protection

They are labeled as Rfbt and Rfbb; I understand the rest of the circuit, but I can't say what exact job those two resistors do.

[image]

Comment: Looks like they are used to set the output voltage Vout, by providing a divided down version of that voltage to the feedback (FB) pin of U1, the boost converter IC.

Comment: Did you look at the data sheet for the TPS61230?

Comment: The name of the resistors suggest "Resistor Feedback TOP" and "Resistor Feedback BOTTOM".

Answer (score 4):

FB is the Feedback pin of the IC. Feedback means that the IC self regulate the output voltage, which is monitored by the Feedback pin.

As you can see in the datasheet, the maximum voltage that can be applied to the feed back pin is much less than the output voltage itself, so the resistors act like a voltage divider to set the correct voltage to the feedback pin.

The voltage can be express as: Vfb=Vout x (Rfbb/(Rtfbt+Rfbb)).

Heres the print of table 7.5 in the datasheet which states the maximum values of Vout and Vfb

[image]